# How can I configure the SFTP-SSH Connector for Azure Logic Apps to transfer files in "Windows" format?

Tags: file, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that retrieves PGP files from some client's SFTP server and stores them in one of our storage accounts. The logic app worked flawlessly until we start receiving files over 50 Mb. Due to the limitation build into the (decprecated) SFTP Connector we had to replace it with the **SFTP-SSH Connector**. The problem is that this new connector doesn't transfer files in the same manner at the previous one or the FileZilla Client does. I don't know the magic sauce that FileZilla or the old SFTP Connector was adding to the file to make them adequate for decryption in Windows.

For example, using FileZilla a file shows as having **36,693 bytes** on the client's server but when I download it using FileZilla or the old connector I am getting a file with **37,017 bytes** and that goes through the rest of the process without a hitch.

With the new connector I get a file with exactly 36,693 bytes that cannot be used.

So, my question is what are those **324 extra bytes** and how can I get the SFTP-SSH connector to add them? (my guess is that it has something to do with the line endings, unix vs. Windows but I don't know).

---

Here is the connector I'm talking about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh